# Libsass&Dart-sass give different result as to chaining of CSS selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, scss-mixins

Let's say I would like to generate below CSS selecor from SASS

.btn.btn {}

But I ended up getting different results with **dart-sass** and one from **lib-sass**

As a frontend dev I used to use sass-loader => node-sass => lib-sass

How can I get around this?

---

```
 %color {
    color: red;
}

@mixin getOverridedSelector{
    &#{&} {
        @content;
    }
}

.test{
       @include getOverridedSelector{
       @extend %color;
     }
}
```

---

**Expected result:**

```
.test.test{
      color: red;
 }
```

**dart-sass actual result:**

```
 .test.test{
      color: red;
 }
```

**lib-sass actual result:**

```
 .test{
      color: red;
 }
```

Comment: hm. &#{&} is working well for me.

Comment: This is very useful for testing SASS etc btw: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: seems like they fixed it in 2019 and my code example is the new unit test :)

Answer (score 1):

### this appears to be a bug in lib-sass and ruby-sass

ignore the following since OP is asking for `@extend` that clearly causes a bug.

just use dart-sass instead.

---

```
@mixin getOverridedSelector {
  &#{&} {
    @content;
  }
}

.foo {
  @include getOverridedSelector {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

this is working well for me. why do you have that `&&` line in there in the first place?

there you can see it in action: https://codepen.io/GottZ/pen/EqoBmb

Comment: Just updated post and I missed an important detail that @extend directive will break the result and that's why my local doesn't work as expected. 
How to get around this?

Comment: hmm.. agreed. that's definitely a problem. i'll dig around and try a few things.

Comment: the `@extend` seems to break it for some strange reason.

Comment: I figured it out that dart-sass compiler works pefectly even with @extend directive but Libsass compiler failed

Comment: @DengZhebin i reported this issue on the libsass github now: https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2959

Comment: feel free to give it a thumbs up